# How can I arrange the elements so that they look good in mobile mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 main elements:

1- where are the social networks.
2- Where my name would be and make the change.
3- Where there is a short explanation with lorem ipsum.

I don't know how to make it so that when the screen becomes smaller at a size of 900 px the explanation with the lorem ipsum is below the name and the icons are in static mode so that when you go down they stay in the same position all the time.

```css
aside {
  display: flex;
}

aside div.contact-ways {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}

aside div.name-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
}

aside div.explanation-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}

.contact-icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
}

.contact-icon:hover {
  left: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.contact-ways article {
  background-color: wheat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.contact-ways article:hover {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.name-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
}

.name-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: rgb(158, 50, 50);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgb(97, 50, 50), 3px 3px 0px rgb(58, 39, 39), 6px 6px 0px black;
}

.name-content ul li:hover {
  font-size: 75px;
  color: rgb(31, 186, 224);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgb(11, 109, 60), 3px 3px 0px rgb(28, 77, 52), 6px 6px 0px rgb(42, 61, 52);
  display: inline;
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "FirstName";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(1):hover:before {
  content: "About";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "LastName";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(2):hover:before {
  content: "Todo";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "LastName2";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(3):hover:before {
  content: "Contact";
}

.explanation-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 946px) {
  aside {}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main class="all-content-page">
    <header>
      <center>Ma page</center>
    </header>

    <aside>
      <div class="contact-ways">
        <article>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/soymusta/">
            <img alt="Instagram icon" src="./images/instagram.png" class="contact-icon" />
          </a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/soymusta1">
            <img alt="Twitter icon" src="./images/twitter.png" class="contact-icon" />
          </a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <a href="https://gitlab.com/musstaa.delyan/porfolio">
            <img alt="Git lab icon" src="./images/git-icon.png" class="contact-icon" />
          </a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <a href="./images/moncv.pdf">
            <img alt="Cv icon" src="./images/cv.png" class="contact-icon" />
          </a>
        </article>
      </div>

      <div class="name-container">
        <form class="name-content">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="explanation-container">
        <form class="explanation-content">
          <strong>
                <p style="font-family:Arial,serif; text-align: justify;"><span class="typed">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
              </strong>
        </form>
      </div>

    </aside>
    <footer>
    </footer>

  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: `How to make it look good` is opinion-based and as such would not fit SO. You have to know what and how you want to achieve something. But basic hint: `media queries`. Using so much absolute position will get you poor outcome as there are way better and modern designing tools (css-grid e.g.). Last but not least, there are no special tutorials to be used with `lorem ipsum` lorem ipsum is just a random text that has simlair behavior then a real test and is betetr for testing then just a very long string that has no word break.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code for basic styles to just provide an idea of how it could be done. When reviewing other's answers, I found that the transition is not preserved. Hence, I have preserved it and here is the code.

```css
aside {
  display: flex;
}

aside div.contact-ways {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
}

aside div.name-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
}

aside div.explanation-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}

.contact-icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
}

.contact-icon:hover {
  left: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.contact-ways {
  position: absolute;
}

.contact-ways article {
  background-color: wheat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.contact-ways article:hover {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.name-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
}

.name-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: rgb(158, 50, 50);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgb(97, 50, 50), 3px 3px 0px rgb(58, 39, 39), 6px 6px 0px black;
}

.name-content ul li:hover {
  font-size: 75px;
  color: rgb(31, 186, 224);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgb(11, 109, 60), 3px 3px 0px rgb(28, 77, 52), 6px 6px 0px rgb(42, 61, 52);
  display: inline;
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "FirstName";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(1):hover:before {
  content: "About";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "LastName";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(2):hover:before {
  content: "Todo";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "LastName2";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(3):hover:before {
  content: "Contact";
}

.explanation-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 946px) {
  aside div.explanation-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 30%;
  }
  aside div.name-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  aside.contact-ways {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="all-content-page">
  <header>
    <center>Ma page</center>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <div class="contact-ways">
      <article>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/soymusta/">
          <img alt="Instagram icon" src="./images/instagram.png" class="contact-icon" />
        </a>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/soymusta1">
          <img alt="Twitter icon" src="./images/twitter.png" class="contact-icon" />
        </a>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="https://gitlab.com/musstaa.delyan/porfolio">
          <img alt="Git lab icon" src="./images/git-icon.png" class="contact-icon" />
        </a>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="./images/moncv.pdf">
          <img alt="Cv icon" src="./images/cv.png" class="contact-icon" />
        </a>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="name-container">
      <form class="name-content">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="explanation-container">
      <form class="explanation-content">
        <strong>
                        <p style="font-family:Arial,serif; text-align: justify;"><span class="typed">Lorem Ipsum is
                                simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
                                five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
                    </strong>
      </form>
    </div>

  </aside>
  <footer>
  </footer>

</main>
```

PS: I have only added the media tags for the width, not the height. Hence, please add the necessary to make it the way you would like it to be. Also, add required number of media tags to make it responsive. Finally, as some have mentioned, try reducing many `position:absolute;` and look for alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

There were a number of small issues;

1.

In the HTML file I replaced the 'center' element with a 'span' and added a class to the header.
I did this because 'center' is not a HTML5 element and the class name will help with styling.

```html
<!-- Before -->
<body>
  <main class="all-content-page">
    <header>
      <center>Ma page</center>
    </header>

    <aside>

<!-- After -->
<body>
  <main class="all-content-page">
    <header class="header">
      <span>Ma page</span>
    </header>

    <aside>
```

2. In the CSS file I made a couple of changes.

- added some style to the 'body' element ( to remove unnecessary margin/padding as well as to ensure the page takes full height of view)
- added style to 'header' element to center the 'span' as well as add font weight to page heading
- commented out the 'position: absolute' property from everywhere its declared ( as well as 'top, left, right' properties )
- introduced flex property to handle positioning for elements within 'main', 'aside', and 'div.contact-ways' elements.
- made the necessary changes to the flex property for the 'aside', and 'div.contact-ways' elements with the @media rule to adjust when screen max-width is smaller than 946px.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.all-content-page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: larger;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

aside div.contact-ways {
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 30%; */
}

aside div.name-container {
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%; */
}

aside div.explanation-container {
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%; */
}

.contact-icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
}

.contact-icon:hover {
  left: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.contact-ways article {
  background-color: wheat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.contact-ways article:hover {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.name-content {
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
}

.name-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: rgb(158, 50, 50);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgb(97, 50, 50), 3px 3px 0px rgb(58, 39, 39), 6px 6px 0px black;
}

.name-content ul li:hover {
  font-size: 75px;
  color: rgb(31, 186, 224);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgb(11, 109, 60), 3px 3px 0px rgb(28, 77, 52), 6px 6px 0px rgb(42, 61, 52);
  display: inline;
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "FirstName";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(1):hover:before {
  content: "About";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "LastName";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(2):hover:before {
  content: "Todo";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "LastName2";
}

.name-content ul li:nth-child(3):hover:before {
  content: "Contact";
}

.explanation-container {
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 35%;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 946px) {
  aside {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  aside div.contact-ways {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }

}
```

Comment: it is correct that `<center>` has been deprecated within HTML5. However every browser supports HTML4 aswell. The real reason not to use it, is that you can center text within CSS and as such you can make style changes without having to hardcode HTML markup. Replacing a `<center>` tag is a stupid idea (not meant as an offense). It does no work as intended as your sample shows. `<span>` is an inline-element and does not span the entire width by default. As such the text will not be centered. you remove the span and apply `text-align: center` to the parent element.

Comment: `body { height: 100%; }` is a useless declaration. `height: 100%` means that an element should consume 100% height of the parent element that needs a defined not a calculated height. First the `<body>` has no parent and second evenif you would count `<html>` as its parent, then it would have a calculated height not a defined one. `body { padding: 0; }` will also output possible bad behavior and is unecessary. The white-space around the website caused by the margin. However there was no reason to "fix" it as this was not asked for nor has to do anythign with the issues.

Answer (score -1):

Always be carefull with positioning elements as '**absolute**' when you don't use relative (separate) positioned containers. But in this case you could add this CSS rules to your media-query to achieve what you want (I hope):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 946px) {
  
  aside {
    display: block;  
   }
  
  aside div.name-container, aside div.explanation-container {
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 12px;
  }
  
  aside div.contact-ways {
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  aside div.name-content {
    position: relative;  
  }
  
 aside div.explanation-container {
   position: relative;
   top: auto;
   left: auto;
   padding-left: 120px;
   width: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-right: 30px;
  }
  
  aside div.name-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
  }
  
  .name-content {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Here's the final JSFiddle to check it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/hielkio/csa2je0z/69/

I hope I / it helped you a bit :-)

Comment: Please also read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) that applies also to any other external content like fiddle or codepens. Fiddles may be used as extension to an existing code snippet. But a working codesnippet must always be included in the question/answer directly for the mentioned reasons above.